# in app email is receiving SIGABRT message

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a contact button to my app that would allow for the user to send me an email in the app, but when I test the feature I am receiving a SIGABRT message. I know the button is connected correctly in interface builder and I have added the messageUI framework to my app. Below is a copy of my code.

AboutMain.m

```
#import "AboutMain.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@implementation AboutMain

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}  


-(IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@gmail.com", nil]];
        [composer setSubject:@"Question"];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"I have a question," isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        [composer release];
    }
    else
        [composer release];
}


-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    if (error){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error:%@",[error description]]delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss"otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }

    else{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }


}
```

AboutMain.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>




@interface AboutMain : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

}
-(IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;


@end
```

Output:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 4176.
2011-06-19 22:30:01.987 DominickGameApp[4176:207] -[UIViewController showEmail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7035780
2011-06-19 22:30:01.990 DominickGameApp[4176:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController showEmail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7035780'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x010675a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011bb313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x010690bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00fd8966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00fd8522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0036f4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x003ff799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00401c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x004007d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x00393ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x00374c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x00379f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0151b992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x01048944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00fa8cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00fa5f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00fa5840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00fa5761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0151a1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0151a289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x0037dc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  DominickGameApp                     0x00002690 main + 102
    22  DominickGameApp                     0x00002621 start + 53
    23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Comment: When does it crash? when you present the compose or when you recieve the didFinishWithResult? Any useful information in the stacktrace?

Comment: @sosborn sorry, it's crashing as soon as i press and release the showEmail button.

Comment: If it is crashing, there is a backtrace.  Post it.

Comment: This is the key to your troubles: reason: '-[UIViewController showEmail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x702a7c0'. What does AboutMain.h inherit from? How is it set up in IB?

Answer (score 3):

> 2011-06-19 22:08:59.902
>   DominickGameApp[3661:207]
>   -[UIViewController showEmail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x702a7c0

The problem is that you are sending the `showEmail` method to an instance of `UIViewController, not an instance of`AboutMain`.

Are you sure you set the class correctly in Interface Builder?   If instantiating via code, make sure you are instantiating an instance of `AboutMain`.

---

Something ain't hooked up right.   Make absolutely sure that there are no console messages before the crash and that the xib file is configured correctly.

Comment: I think so, I am new to obj-c and xcode. Is there a way I can check to make sure it is correct? thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention, I updated the code above to reflect the suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement for the MessageUI framework is incorrect. Try changing it to this:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

**UPDATED**
IBActions should be declared as:

```
-(IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender
```

You are missing the (id)sender part. Add that and then get back to us.

Comment: Here is a copy of the output:

Comment: The output didn't post. Please try again.

Comment: @sosborn I edited the original posted and added the output, Thanks.

Comment: This is the key to your troubles: reason: '-[UIViewController showEmail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x702a7c0'. What does AboutMain.h inherit from? How is it set up in IB?

Comment: The `sender` part is actually optional.

Comment: @bbum- thanks - that is good to know. By the way - since I've got you here I just want to say thanks for all of the great blog posts. They've been extremely educational throughout the years.